# Java : output the first 5 integer that can be divided by 3 within 0-100

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            int num  = 0; 
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                num++;
            }

            if (num == 5) 
                break;              
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my code, but I got the result of all the integers that can be divided by 3 from 0 to 100.

I am a beginner for Java, so can somebody tell me where did I do wrong? (I am not seeking alternative solutions for this question, just explanation why the loop doesn't stop when num == 5).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are resetting num to 0 in the for loop so it's always zero.

Comment: Actually it's always 0 or 1

Comment: Move  the initialization of num to so that it's before the for loop.

Comment: One way you could have found this on your own is to add: `System.out.println( "num=" + num );` on the line before the if statement

Comment: `IntStream.range(1, 100).filter(x -> x % 3 == 0).limit(5).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why `100`?

Comment: @shmosel I took OP's range. I suppose it should be `rangeClosed` but `100` isn't divisible by `3`. Or just `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).map(x -> x * 3).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're getting *all* of the numbers divisible by `3` from `0-100` is because you're redefining `num` each iteration of the loop to zero. Just place the initialization outside of the loop, then increment like you are inside.

```
int num = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
        num++;
    }

    if (num == 5) break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with answers you can mathematically prove are wrong?

```
int num = 3;
int count = 0;
while ((num < 100) && (count < 5)) {
        System.out.println(num);
        num+=3;
        count++;
}
```